# how to execute same piece of code for both if and else

Tags: java

```
if {
        condition fails move it
        some location xxx
        }
        else {
        execute different condition and move it
        same location xxx
    }
```

Here how can i put the location common for both conditions

Comment: You have to put it at the end of the if statement. That's it.

Comment: @raja you can  define method which will be common .

Comment: Why does it have to be inside the if/else when it made no difference with any arguments? Why not just put that in front or after of the if/else block?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with what you're trying to accomplish? What do you mean by same location xxx, do you mean some array you're adding to? Or moving?

Comment: simply put the same location xxx code outside the if else block

Answer (score 3):

If your common statement `same location xxx` doesn't need to be in **if-else** then put it out of the **if-else**.
I guess you want this.

```
if{
     condition fails move it
}
else{
     execute different condition and move it
}
same location xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware, this is some kind of pseudo-code, not Java:

```
if (condition) {
    //some code
} else {
    //some code
}

//common code
```

OR

```
if (condition) {
    //some code
    common();
} else {
    //some code
    common();
}

void common(){
    //common code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What about creating a method moveToLocationXXX() and calling it in both places? I mean:

```
if(conditionFails) {
   moveToLocationXXX()
} else {
  execute different condition
  moveToLocationXXX()
}

private void moveToLocationXXX(params...) {
   do whatever is needed to move to location XXX
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16556369)

Comment: I think the user who asked the question is the one who can tell if my answer is clear enough. And I think it answers the question.

Comment: You don't just answer for the user who asks the question. You answer for anyone else in the future who comes to this site with the same problem. Keep that in mind the next time you write an answer.

Comment: Hi RDM! Please note that this comment is marked as "From Review" which means this answer was placed in the Low Quality Posts Review Queue automatically by the system. The comment is automatically generated by the review system based on the flag the reviewer (in this case, me) gives it, and we cannot edit the comment. As @Lexi mentioned, the *vast majority* of the readers of your answer over time will not be the person who originally asked the question. Extra context and explanation are thus invaluable. The intent is to improve the overall quality of the site, not to troll you :)

Comment: Ok, I understand. You can see I changed my answer to be more complete.